# Same code yields different result when printing index of a list

Tags: python, loops, indexing, nested-lists

```
master = [[2,3],[5,1,3]]
mySection = 2

availableList = []
for entry in master[mySection-1]:
    if entry != 0:
        availableList.append(master[mySection-1].index(entry))
        print(master[mySection-1].index(entry))
```

This code prints the index of the specified sublist perfectly since it prints 0, 1, 2

```
master = [[2,3],[0,0,3]]
mySection = 2

inUseList = []
for entry in master[mySection-1]:
    if entry == 0:
        inUseList.append(master[mySection-1].index(entry))
        print(master[mySection-1].index(entry))
```

This code is supposed to print the index of a specified sublist the same way the other code did. The only thing I changed here is the if-condition and the master list to include zeros, yet it prints 0, 0 which is not the index

At first I thought it was a logic error since I was creating a larger project, but I tested both individually and even rewrote them and got the same result. How can I make the second set of code print the index instead of the element inside the index?

Comment: `index` returns the index of the _first_ matching item.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.index()` returns the index of the *first* instance of a given element. Since `0` appears at both index 0 and 1, calling `.index(0)` returns 0.

What you're looking for is printing the actual index of the given element, rather than the return value of `.index()`. This can be done using `enumerate()`:

```py
for index, entry in enumerate(master[mySection-1]):
    if entry == 0:
        inUseList.append(index)
        print(index)
```

Comment: I had never worked with indexing to this extent. I really appreciate the insight. I have changed both to use enumerate().